# Firestore arrayUnion with duplicate entries

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array in my Firestore database, let's say its [0, 2, 5] and I want to add another array with the values [1, 3, 5]. When I add my array with `arrayUnion` it only adds the elements which don't already exist. So far so good, I read in the documentation that arrayUnion is supposed to do that, but how can I add the full array including the duplicates that my final array in the database looks like so [0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]? I couldn't find any documentation about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I add the full array including the duplicates that my final array in the database looks like so [0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]?

Simply, read the document, get the array, add the duplicate elements, write the document back. Using the `arrayUnion` is not an option in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble with that. If you have a list read the document just as Alex Mamo said. This is what I did with mine.

```
//To access the database or however you have it
FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

//Creating temp List to hold the values
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

//Populating the temp array:REPLACE THIS WITH HOW YOU READ YOUR DATA
for (String TIMES_S : parking.getStartTimeArray()) {
    temp.add(TIMES_S);
}

//Here add values to your array that you want to update 
//In my case they are strings
temp.add("xxxxx");

//Updating the array in your documents
database.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION").document("YOUR_DOCUMENT_THAT_HOLDS_THE_ARRAY")
    .update("YOUR_ARRAY_NAME", temp);
```